# Flatabulous theme does not show correct window decoration on Gnome Shell

Tags: gnome, 16.04, themes

The GTK style is correct but the window decoration defaults to another theme.

https://github.com/anmoljagetia/Flatabulous

Example:

[image]

Comment: Interesting, how did you install the Flatabulous theme for Ubuntu GNOME 16.04? Can you install manually instead (see https://github.com/anmoljagetia/Flatabulous#3-manually) instead and see if that helps?

Comment: Yes that was the method I used to install it.  I also tried moving the theme to /usr/share/themes with the same result.

Comment: Ah I see. I saw from the GitHub repo issues that manual installation helped some people, but I guess it didn't help you. Might be better to create an issue at the GitHub repo and see if the maintainer has a solution.

Comment: Are you still looking for answers?